# Conversion from String to datetime (yyyy-mm-dd hh:mm:ss) in Pyspark

Tags: apache-spark, pyspark

The column in dataframe look like:-

```
Input--> 20191106 ---Output---> 2019-11-06 00:00:00
Input--> 20180815--Output---> 2018-08-15 00:00:00
```

Code:

```
from pyspark.sql.functions import from_unixtime, unix_timestamp
df.withColumn("newcol", from_unixtime(unix_timestamp(df("coldt"), "YYYY--MM-DD HH:MM:SS")))
```

Error:

```
File "C:/Users/nance.py", line 14, in <module>
    df.withColumn("newcol", from_unixtime(unix_timestamp(df("coldt"), "YYYY--MM-DD HH:MM:SS")))
TypeError: 'DataFrame' object is not callable
```

Please help.

Comment: Probably typo in `df("coldt")`. Shouldn't it be `df["coldt"]` ?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

just use [to_timestamp](https://spark.apache.org/docs/latest/api/python/pyspark.sql.html?highlight=dateformat#pyspark.sql.functions.to_timestamp) function.

Working example:

```py
import pyspark.sql.functions as F
df = spark.createDataFrame([['20191106'],['20180815']])
df = df.withColumn('dates',F.to_timestamp('_1','yyyyMMdd'))
display(df)
```

Comment: Thanks a lot, but it is giving error as : pyspark.sql.utils.AnalysisException: u"cannot resolve 'unix_timestamp(`VDTL`, 'yyyyMMdd')' due to data type mismatch: argument 1 requires (string or date or timestamp) type, however, '`VDTL`' is of bigint type. Please help me.

Comment: df = df.withColumn('dates',F.to_timestamp('col','yyyyMMdd')), but unfortunately it is throwing error as " cannot resolve 'unix_timestamp(`colA`, 'yyyyMMdd')' due to data type mismatch: argument 1 requires (string or date or timestamp) type, however, '`colA`' is of bigint type

Comment: Cast `colA` to `string`, then use to_timestamp()